# .app file is too large after implemented the bridging concept in my existing objective C project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, bridge, .app

Recently i learning swift, so I used bridging concept in existing project. After successfully bridging my app .app file increased double the time. Is any one can guide me to reduce the size with swift file? Or want i remove bridging from my Project to reduce the ipa file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift libraries are included in your build for compatibility reasons in future. The only way to avoid it is not to use Swift.

Comment: Thanks Dvole. Can i explain the proper way to remove the swifit file completly from my project?

Comment: Create your project selecting "Objective-C" instead of "Swift", and after that only add classes that are Objective-C (not Swift).

Comment: ok, But i implemented swift in objective c. How can i remove swift and related files from my project with error?